# changing Html.Raw into string without html markup in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Quite simple question. I have the following code

```
@Html.Raw(following.Description).ToString()
```

when this comes from database it has some markup in it (its a forum post but i want to show a snippet in the list without the markup

is there any way to remove this and replace this line or shall I just regex it from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a utility class extension method that is able to strip tags from fragments without using Regex:

```
public static string StripTags(this string markup)
{
    try
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(markup);
        XPathDocument doc;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr,
                       new XmlReaderSettings()
                       {
                           ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
                           // for multiple roots
                       }))
        {
            doc = new XPathDocument(xr);
        }

        return doc.CreateNavigator().Value; // .Value is similar to .InnerText of  
                                           //  XmlDocument or JavaScript's innerText
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```